# Is cached content served while the cache is regenerating?

Tags: cache

I've always been unclear on this (it would be nice to include in the documentation). Let's say I use a cache tag like so:

```
{% cache for 1 hour %}
```

After an hour has passed, will the next user to load the page receive the cached version while the cache is being regenerated, or will they experience a slow page load while the cache is being regenerated?

Answer (score 1):

> will they experience a slow page load while the cache is being regenerated?

That one. After a cached item is expired, the next person to request that item will cause it to regenerate and take any performance penalty that involves.

Comment: Got it—thanks! Any way to change that behavior? I'd like to cache for shorter periods without users randomly experiencing slow page loads.

Comment: At that point, you'll probably want to look into something like https://plugins.craftcms.com/blitz for caching and cache warming.